# How to increase the space between divs

Tags: html, css

I am trying to style an html segment

```
<div class="itemDisplay">
    <div class="itemLables"> Item Number :</div>
    <div class="itemData">1</div>
    <br>
    <div class="itemLables"> Item Name :</div>
    <div class="itemData">new phone</div>
    <br>
    <div class="itemLables"> Category :</div>
    <div class="itemData">phone</div>
    <br>
    <div class="itemLables"> Description:</div>
    <div class="itemData">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, co...</div>
    <br>
    <div class="itemLables"> Buy it now price :</div>
    <div class="itemData">44</div>
    <br>
    <div class="itemLables"> Bid price :</div>
    <div class="itemData">11</div>
    <br>Time left : 10 days, 2 hours, 35 minutes, 43 seconds<br>
<button class="bidButton" id="btnBid1" onclick="submitBid(this.id)">Place Bid</button>
<button class="buyButton" id="btnBuy1" onclick="buyItNow(this.id)">Buy it now</button>
    </div>
```

The css I am using is

```
.itemDisplay {
background-color:#BDBCBA;
margin : 10px;
margin-bottom: 10px;
border : 10px;
display: inline-block;
width : 90%;
position:relative;
}

.itemLables{
            width:200px;
            text-align:right;
            position:absolute;
            left:0;         
}

.itemData{
            text-align:left;
            position:absolute;
            left:220px;
}


.bidButton {
    background-color:#3090C7;
    width: 100px;
    height: 40px;
    margin: 10px;
}

.buyButton {
        background-color:green;
    width: 100px;
    height: 40px;
    margin: 10px;

}
```

The output I am getting is this

[image]

My question is how can we increase the vertical space between each row of the details. I have tried increasing the height for both of the div classes but that does not work. I have tried margin and padding but that also does not increase the vertical spacing.

Comment: did u try line-height?

Comment: didnt make any difference

Comment: Since you are displaying a set of pairs, you better off using `<dl>`, `<dt>` and `<dd>`, instead of that all of those divs with classes. More info [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/dl)

Comment: `Padding` and/or `margin` don't do the job?

Comment: You could wrap a div around every 2 items (for example item number and 1) and give that div a margin-top:5px. But why not use a list instead of all these divs?

Comment: Post a fiddle, if you can.

Answer (score 0):

Make use of float instead of absolute positioning to get the same output and add padding-bottom on both .itemLables and .itemData elements.

```
.itemLables{
  clear:left;
  text-align:right;
  width:200px;
  float:left;
  padding-bottom:5px;

}

.itemData{

            text-align:left;                     
           padding-bottom:5px;
}
```

see demo: http://jsbin.com/wiyojosaje/edit?html,output

Answer (score 0):

One of the issues here is that you are using absolute positioning to place these elements, which can cause them to not respect any margin or padding that you are applying. This can get really messy, especially for something as simple as displaying a series of properties as you currently are.

**Consider a `<table>`**

Being that you want to have your elements spaced equally, you might consider using a `<table>` element. Tables get a bad rap because most people associate them to the days when folks laid out their entire sites using them, however they are perfect for doing exactly what you currently are: displaying tabular data.

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Item Number :</td>
    <td>1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Item Name :</td>
    <td>new phone</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Category :</td>
    <td>phone</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Description :</td>
    <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, co...</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Buy it now price :</td>
    <td>44</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

This obviously isn't the only approach and `<div>` elements could certainly be used to handle this, but tables just might be more appropriate in this case. With a few minor CSS changes, you should be able to quickly achieve the effect you are looking for, while cleaning up your code a bit.

**Example**

[image]

```css
.itemDisplay {
  background-color: #BDBCBA;
  margin: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  border: 10px;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 90%;
  position: relative;
}
/* Center your table */
.itemDisplay table {
  margin: 0 auto; 
}

/* Fix your spacing in your table */
.itemDisplay table td:first-of-type {
  width: 200px;
  text-align: right;
}
.centered-content {
  text-align: center;
}
.bidButton {
  background-color: #3090C7;
  width: 100px;
  height: 40px;
  margin: 10px;
}
.buyButton {
  background-color: green;
  width: 100px;
  height: 40px;
  margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>Tables Ain't Evil</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class='itemDisplay'>
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td>Item Number :</td>
        <td>1</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Item Name :</td>
        <td>new phone</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Category :</td>
        <td>phone</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Description :</td>
        <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, co...</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Buy it now price :</td>
        <td>44</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
    <div class='centered-content'>
      <br />Time left : 10 days, 2 hours, 35 minutes, 43 seconds
      <br />
      <button class="bidButton" id="btnBid1" onclick="submitBid(this.id)">Place Bid</button>
      <button class="buyButton" id="btnBuy1" onclick="buyItNow(this.id)">Buy it now</button>
    </div>

  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you have

```
    .itemDisplay {
background-color:#BDBCBA;
margin : 10px;
margin-bottom: 10px;
border : 10px;
display: inline-block;
width : 90%;
position:relative;
}

.itemLables{
            width:200px;
            text-align:right;
            position:relative;
            float: left;
            padding-top:20px;
            left:0;         
}

.itemData{
            text-align:left;
            position:relative;
            width: calc(90% - 200px);
            padding-top:20px;
            float: left;

}
```

Changing the padding-top in itemLables and itemData you can change the space

Answer (score 0):

Here is a much simplified version, using a definition list.

```css
.itemDisplay {
  background-color:#BDBCBA;
  margin : 10px;
  border : 10px;
  display: inline-block;
  width : 90%;
  position:relative;
  
  line-height: 1.5em;
}

dt {
  width:200px;
  text-align:right;
  display: inline-block;
}

dt:after {
  content: ' :';
}

dd {
  text-align:left;
  display: inline;
  margin-left: 10px;
}

dd:after { /* new line after the value */
  content: '\A';
  white-space: pre;
}


footer {
  text-align: center;
}

.bidButton,
.buyButton {
    background-color: #3090C7;
    width: 100px;
    height: 40px;
    margin: 10px;
}

.buyButton {
    background-color:green;
}
```

```html
<div class="itemDisplay">
    <dl>
      <dt>Item Number</dt>
      <dd>1</dd>

      <dt>Item Name</dt>
      <dd>new phone</dd>

      <dt>Category</dt>
      <dd>phone</dd>
      
      <dt>Description</dt>
      <dd>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, co...</dd>

      <dt>Buy it now price</dt>
      <dd>44</dd>

      <dt>Bid price</dt>
      <dd>11</dd>
    </dl>

    Time left : 10 days, 2 hours, 35 minutes, 43 seconds
  
  <footer>
    <button class="bidButton" id="btnBid1" onclick="submitBid(this.id)">Place Bid</button>
    <button class="buyButton" id="btnBuy1" onclick="buyItNow(this.id)">Buy it now</button>
  </footer>
  
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Is not very good idea to use `<br>` between divs. I'd try this way:

```
.itemContainer {
    margin-bottom: 50px;
}

.itemLbl {
    width: 200px;
    float: left;
    text-align: right;
}

.itemDat {
    width: 200px;
    float: left;
    text-align: left;
    padding-left: 20px;
}
```

and then:

```
<div class="itemContainer">
    <div class="itemLbl">Description:</div>
    <div class="itemDat">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, co...</div>
</div>

<div class="itemContainer">
    <div class="itemLbl">Description:</div>
    <div class="itemDat">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, co...</div>
</div>
```

and play with margin-bottom.